# Ferrule to mount hydraulic disc brake hose to frame

Tags: disc-brake

Is there some kind of ferrule(or similar) that can be used to fasten a hydraulic disc brake hose to the braze-ons of a frame that used to have v-brakes? The hose is to thin to stick to the braze-ons, so I need something that will keep it in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.bicyclehero.com/gb/jagwire-4-5mm-housing-hose-loop-guide-cable-dca059.html

This is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

BikeParts.com/problemsolvers has an adapter that converts cable stops into hose clamps the part# [BPC317673](http://bikeparts.com/search_results.asp?ID=BPC317673).

Comment: I think those are meant for smaller braze-ons than mine, where the hose is to thick to be inserted into the braze-on. I need something to make my hose thicker.